# PyDev - how to include new apps in the project

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I have created a new app inside a django project using the command line: `python manage.py startapp name` and I'm using PyDev as my IDE for the first time.

My problem is that I can't add this app to the project so I can begin to code. I have been reading some questions and answers but so far I couldn't find a answer. Can you help me, please?

I'm using eclipse mars and I installed PyDev using the market place.

Comment: What is stopping you adding the app? You just edit the settings.py file. This has nothing to do with pydev or eclipse

Comment: I can create the app, no problem with that. I just wanted to add this app in the project. I've tried to restart the IDE to see if the new folder appear, but nothing. I will have to open the file as a separated one if I want to edit it

Comment: Did you add it into INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yes, I did. I installed the LiClipse and there the new app appears. I'm using this IDE now.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the context menu (right click on project in project explorer) and choose django/start new app.